# Consumo con URLSession y clousure, respuesta vacia fuera de clousure

Tags: api, ios, swift, xcode

Estoy empezando con swift y xcode, y me encontrado con un pequeño problema, al querer pintar  en un mapa unas cordenadas que vienen de una API, resulta que el arreglo esta vacio fuera de mi clousure, pero dentro del clousure si tiene asignada la respuesta de la API en el arreglo.
Alguna razon de porque este pasando esto?

```
class AppNetworkUtil {

func requestEcobiciStations(completionHandler: @escaping (Cordenates) -> Void) {
    if let url = URL(string: AppConstant.API_BASE + AppConstant.END_POINT_ECOBICI) {
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            
            guard let safeData = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let decodeData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Cordenates.self, from: safeData)
                completionHandler(decodeData)
            } catch {
                print (error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

}

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var latitud:Double = 19.4326077
var longitud:Double = -99.133208
var appNetworkUtils = AppNetworkUtil()
var mapView: GMSMapView?
var response: [Stations] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppConstant.API_KEY_MAPS)
    
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitud, longitude: longitud, zoom: 10.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.frame, camera: camera)
    view.addSubview(mapView!)
    
    appNetworkUtils.requestEcobiciStations { (stat) in
        self.response = stat.network.stations
        print("Tamaño dentro de clousure: \(self.response.count)")
    }
    
    print("Tamaño fuera de clousure: \(self.response.count)")

}
```

}

La lineas de print muestran en consola lo siguiente:
Tamaño fuera de clousure: 0
...
Tamaño dentro de clousure: 480

Comment: Exactamente cuál es la pregunta? Tienes que pintar las coordenadas dentro del closure cuando recibes la respuesta de la API.

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que las llamadas a los web services se realizan en un hilo asincrono diferente al Main Thread para no congelar la pantalla porque la respuesta del web service puede tomar unas segundos.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppConstant.API_KEY_MAPS)
    
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitud, longitude: longitud, zoom: 10.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.frame, camera: camera)
    view.addSubview(mapView!)
    
    appNetworkUtils.requestEcobiciStations { (stat) in
       // Estos se ejecutan en otro Thread
        self.response = stat.network.stations
        print("Tamaño dentro de clousure: \(self.response.count)")
    }
    // Esta linea se ejecuta en el main Thread
    print("Tamaño fuera de clousure: \(self.response.count)")

}
```

Te recomiendo colocar un breakpoint dentro del closure y otro afuera, te vas a dar cuenta que primero se ejecuta las sentencias fuera del closure.

te recomiendo leer un poco sobre Grand Central Dispatch.